# LWC .js - modify multiple fields with same prefix

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, query

I have several elements which I am showing/hiding using distinct fields defined in my .js.
All of the fields start with "showEdit" and I am using various events to set these to true.
I have a single reset event that I am calling on success or cancel that sets all of the "showEdit" fields to false.
Currently in the reset event I am individually defining each field - below is a small example.  Is there a way to query all fields that start with "showEdit" and set their values to false?
I thought of using querySelectorAll, but was not sure of the

```
  handleReset(event){
        this.showFooter = false;
        this.showEditContact = false;
        this.showEditMatch = false;
        this.showEditCompany = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, also add sample is HTML

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function to do this.

```
resetEditFlags() {
  Object.keys(this).forEach((field) => { 
    if (field.substring(0, 8) === 'showEdit') {
       this[field] = false;
    }
  );
}
```

This will check every property in your controller, and if it starts with `showEdit` (case sensitive), it'll be set to false.

Other formulations of this are also possible, such as:

```
resetEditFlags() {
  Object.keys(this).filter(
    field => field.substring(0, 8) === 'showEdit'
  ).forEach(field => { 
    this[field] = false;
  });
}
```

It really just depends on personal preference.